# Visual Basic 2005 + mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

How do I connect to MySQL and get started with VB 2005?
Been using PHP + MySQL in work for bout a year now. Just wondering how to get started with Visual Basic 2005 + MySQL. Just to connect to a database, and run a simple select star query?

db -> db_name
table -> tbl_name
ip -> localhost

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ADO.NET Driver for MySQL (Connector/NET), which you can download here:
http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

After installing, you can use MySQL in the standard .NET way, using MySqlConnection, MySqlCommand, MySqlDataReader, and so on.  The documentation is here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-programming.html

Some example code:

```
Dim myConnection As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
myConnection.ConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;" _
            & "uid=root;" _
            & "pwd=12345;" _
            & "database=test;"
myConnection.Open()
Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand("select * from TheTable", myConnection)
Using myReader As MySqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
    While myReader.Read()
        Console.WriteLine((myReader.GetInt32(0) & ", " & myReader.GetString(1)))
    End While
End Using
myConnection.Close()
```

The Using statement makes sure the data reader is closed when you no longer need it, even if an exception is thrown.  You could also enclose the connection in a Using statement.